# Returning a JSP in ReST response

Tags: java, jsp, rest, jersey

We are working on an application where we are exposing the services using Jersey - ReST. There are some cases where we need to return the JSP instead of returning only JSON response. I searched over the internet and found some ways to achieve this. Following is the configuration that I have done so far:

**Web.xml**

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>in.test.resource.MyApp</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.JSPTemplatesBasePath</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/jsp</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

**ReST resource Java class**

```
@GET
@Path("/somePath")
public Response getPickListItems(@QueryParam("name") String name) {
    // business logic
    return Response.ok(new Viewable("/myJsp.jsp", "Test")).build();
}
```

Now, when I hit the URL in my browser, I can only see this as a response:
`{"templateName":"/myJsp.jsp","model":"Test","resolvingClass":null,"templateNameAbsolute":true}`

I have referred to [this blog post](http://blog.docuverse.com/2009/08/04/using-jsp-with-jersey-jax-rs-implementation/) as well, but in vain.

I have two questions:

1. Is it really achievable to return a JSP from ReST service response?
2. If yes, is it that I am missing on something?

Comment: I've never really used the MVC feature of Jersey, but from what it states [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/mvc.html#d0e15224), for JSP templating support, the Jersey web application should be registered as a servlet filter, rather than a servlet. See [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet) for filter setup

Comment: @peeskillet Thanks, will have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by using `temporaryRedirect` or `Response`:

```
Response.temporaryRedirect(URI.create("REQUIRED_URL").build();
```